# Emulate Bash jq with Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON in a file called data.json

```json
{
  "tenant_admins": [
    {
      "is_user": true,
      "id": "id-1",
      "user_id": "P000216",
      "email": "test1@test.com",
      "first_name": "Test",
      "last_name": "One",
      "display_name": "Test One",
      "status": "active",
      "roles": {
        "manage_access": true,
        "manage_idp": true
      }
    },
    {
      "is_user": false,
      "id": "id-2",
      "user_id": "P000218",
      "email": "test2@test.com",
      "first_name": "Test",
      "last_name": "Two",
      "display_name": "Test Two",
      "status": "active",
      "roles": {
        "manage_access": true,
        "manage_idp": true
      }
    },
    {
      "is_user": true,
      "id": "id-3",
      "user_id": "P000230",
      "email": "test3@test.com",
      "first_name": "Test",
      "last_name": "Three",
      "display_name": "Test Three",
      "status": "active",
      "roles": {
        "manage_access": true,
        "manage_idp": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run this bash command:

```
cat data.json| jq ".tenant_admins[].id"
```

I get the following response that I expect:

```
"id-1"
"id-2"
"id-3"
```

How can I do the same operation in Python?  So far I've been able to grab that information using the json module, but I have to create a for loop to do so.  Is there anything built-in that I may have missed or am I stuck using a for loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: "_I have to create a for loop to do so_", what is the problem with that? Or is it that you directly want to use your jq queries that you already have?

Comment: Also note that jq is available as a Python package (https://pypi.org/project/jq/) but that seems overkill for this simple task.

Comment: jq's `.[]` acts like a loop; jq's implicit behavior of iterating over all input documents is _also_ a loop. You _already_ have loops in the original code; what's wrong with having loops in the Python?

Comment: You could use a list comprehension to make it a one-liner in python, but you still need a for loop there.

Comment: If you _do_ want to use preexisting jq queries, then the tool jarmod reached is what you should reach for.

Comment: There is a functional approach for that, but it won't be shorter as `[d['id'] for d in data['tenant_admins']]`

Comment: ...sure, but it's still a loop -- just as helpers like `map` are still loops, even if they use different syntax. There's no getting away from loops here, which is why we need the OP to step in and clarify what they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's responses.  With my basic understanding of Python I could use something like this:

---

import json

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for tenant_admin in data['tenant_admins']:
        print(tenant_admin['id'])

---

I realize that jq's [] is doing a loop, but it's behind the scene and I don't need to worry about it.   I wanted to know if there is a capability in Python that is already built in that would accomplish what jq's [] does.

Comment: If not, my thought was to create a function and maybe import it as a module so I could rinse and reuse.  Just didn't want to recreate the wheel if I don't have to.

Comment: @EricP, I don't see why you see loops as something to "worry about". [As the Zen of Python says](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/), "explicit is better than implicit"; writing out a loop is more explicit than having it done behind your back.

Comment: Python and jq have very different execution models; Python's is more general-purpose, jq's is suited to that language's narrower niche, but has a lot more happening behind one's back that would make it hard to reason about if it could be used in scenarios where order-of-operations was important (but since jq is deliberately just a query language with very few side-effecting operations and those it _does_ have mostly specialized for logging/debugging, the weird execution model is something its users mostly don't need to understand).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I appreciate your compare/contrast of explicit vs. implicit and Python vs. jq, but my question is still out there- "I wanted to know if there is a capability in Python that is already built in that would accomplish what jq's [] does?".  No is a completely acceptable answer, if it's correct.  I asked ChatGPT this same question last night and it said there isn't a built in way, but I wanted to ask the folks here to see if anyone thought differently.

Comment: I'm not sure it's answerable, because it comes down to the question of what "counts". I can come up with lots of ways to hide a loop inside other syntax, but I have no idea which of those are enough like jq's `[]` to make you happy.

Comment: To give you an example of what I'm talking about, consider `python3 -c 'import sys, json; print("\n".join(map(lambda f: f["id"], json.loads(sys.stdin.read())["tenant_admins"])))'`. There's no explicit loop, but... does it count? And if I can't _tell_ if it counts by your rules, how should anyone else know?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank @jarmod and @charles duffy for pointing me to the jq python module.  After some poking around, I was able to create the following:

```
import json
import jq

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

ids = jq.compile('.tenant_admins[].id').input(data).all()

# Print the extracted names
print(ids)
```

This results in:

```
['id-1', 'id-2', 'id-3']
```